Django REST ModelViewSet view returns 404 after PATCH
I have ModelViewSet view in django rest framework project. I am trying to filter documents that are not live, I mean are not on main view. To filter I am using params: http://localhost:8000/documents?is_live=false. I have list of records. After set true on one of objects I'm getting 404 error

"GET /api/documents/?is_live=false HTTP/1.1" 200
test {'pk': '2', 'partial': True}
Not Found: /api/documents/2/
Not Found: /api/documents/2/
"PATCH /api/documents/2/ HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /api/documents/?is_live=false HTTP/1.1" 200

Funny thing is, when I have this code below, without filter(is_live=True) is working:
def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.query_params.get('is_live'):
            return self.queryset.filter(is_live=False)
        return self.queryset.all()

My view's code and custom filter (django_filters) are below:
class DocumentFilter(dfilters.FilterSet):
    is_live = dfilters.BooleanFilter(field_name='is_live')

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['is_live']


class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    filterset_class = DocumentFilter
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['title', 'category']
    ordering_fields = [
        'title',
        'category',
    ]

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("test", args, kwargs)
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['patch'])
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.query_params.get('is_live'):
            return self.queryset.filter(is_live=False)
        return self.queryset.filter(is_live=True)

EDIT
models.py
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Document"
        verbose_name_plural = "Documents"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

project.urls
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    ...
]

api.url
apirouter = routers.DefaultRouter()
...
apirouter.register('documents', DocumentViewSet)
...

I would like to have possibility to partial update of object on filtered view.

Please provide a [mre]. Where is your URLconf for "/api/documents/2/"?

@chukwujiobi-canon pls check my edit

Seems that the url you are trying to access is not added to django. So it returns 404.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
